# Unable to join tables from 2 tables with many to many condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this diagram below, I am trying to first computes the total number of suppliers supplying the specified part then extracts the supplier’s information supplying the specified part.

```sql
SELECT count(*) totalCount, s_suppkey, s_name                                               
FROM supplier INNER JOIN part ON s_suppkey = p_suppkey
WHERE p_partkey = 123
GROUP BY s_suppkey, s_name;
```

[image]
But i keep getting this error `ORA-00904: "P_SUPPKEY": invalid identifier`

Comment: Take a closer look at your diagram. There is no `P_SUPPKEY`.

Comment: Are you sure this is 1:n? Looks like m:n to me. That would also explain why we don't see the linking column - it's in the bridge table, which in your diagram seems to be that box left of the line.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes it a many to many relation, i have updated the picture

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables because, although your diagram shows a relationship between the tables, there are no columns in common between the two tables where that relationship is implemented so it is impossible for a relationship to actually exist between the tables.

Comment: I am not familiar with this diagram type. I'd expect the bridge table either not to be shown at all (then it is modeled by the line only) or to be complete with the linking columns. Your diagram is showing the table, but the columns are missing from it. We can only assume that in your database they are there. So join the three tables on suppkey and partkey.

Comment: Please show us what the final result is supposed to look like. So far, if your query did work, it would return the part count per supplier (which is always 1, because you are looking up only one part and the suppliers that ship it).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your diagram, there is no such column in the `part` table,

Answer (score 0):

You (probably) need to use the (bridging) table that is part-hidden off to the left of your image that connects the parts and suppliers in a many-to-many relationship.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () totalCount,
       s_suppkey,
       s_name                                               
FROM   supplier s
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   part_supplied_by ps
         WHERE  s.s_suppkey = ps.s_suppkey
         AND    p.p_partkey = 123
       );
```

Comment: i have updated the picture im not sure if i have to use that side table

Comment: @Best Jeanist: How else would you know which supplier ships which part?